# SharePoint 2013 - MyProfile - Custom Ribbon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

Hy, I hope my question isn't too silly.

I'm using Visual-Studio 2013 and I want to ask if it's possible to create a custom ribbon for the SharePoint 2013 MyProfile site to add a button in it that runs a C# code. And if it's possible how to do it.

I hope anyone is able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Visual studio 2012. VS 2013 does not exist.
Yes, It is possible and not that difficult. You need to add a custom action to the Elements.xml file and deploy it using a package.

You can get selected items on the page(if any) by using client object model/ecmascript and pass the parameters to a custom page where you can run your code. You can also do a postback and handle your custom code on the same page using a web part or any other parameters.

See this blog on how to create a custom action on ribbon...
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfrost/archive/2009/11/06/adding-custom-button-to-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon.aspx

You can also do this in designer..see this blog..
[Adding Custom Actions to the Ribbon UI in SharePoint 2010 Using SharePoint Designer 2010](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/adding-custom-actions-to-the-ribbon-ui-in-sharepoint-2010-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)